# Minimal perimeter of cuboid, given base and lateral area

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-verification

Consider a cuboid, or rectangular parallelepiped (all faces are rectangles). Denote length of its base edges $a, b$ and height $h$. Assume that the base area

$$ L = ab $$

and lateral area

$$ S = 2(ah + bh) = 2h (a+b)$$

are constant. What is the minimum value for the perimeter (sum of all edge lengths)

$$ P = 4(a+b+h)?$$

I can prove, using AM-GM or derivatives, that

$$ P/4 = a+b+h = \frac{S}{2h} + h \geq \sqrt{2S}$$

and choose minimal

$$ h = \sqrt{\frac{S}{2}} \tag{1}$$

Then elementary transformations yield

$$ a = \sqrt{\frac{S}{8}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{S}{8} - L} $$
$$ b = \sqrt{\frac{S}{8}} \mp \sqrt{\frac{S}{8} - L} $$

but $a, b$ are undefined for $S < 8L$. Surely a cuboid allows for any positive values of $S, L$. So evaluation $(1)$ was apparently too strong.

How should I proceed in the case $S < 8L$?

Comment: It seems like a general solution could be obtained using Lagrange multipliers - have you tried that?

Comment: @Titus No, I haven't. I'm rather more interested why AM-GM is too strong here.

Comment: I think your method doesn't work because when you substitute $a+b=S/(2h)$ you are not taking into account that $a$ and $b$ are not free parameters but are constrained by $ab=L$. That means $h$ is constrained too.

Comment: I've added to my answer an explanation of the reason why you can't treat the case $S<8L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply solve $b=L/a$ and $h=(S/2)/(a+L/a)$ and plug these into your formula for $P/4$. You get a function of $a$ only which can be derived: the resulting equation is of third degree in $x=a^2$:

$$
x^3-\left({S\over2}-L\right)x^2+\left({S\over2}-L\right)Lx-L^3=0.
$$

Factoring out the solution $x=L$ one can also find the other two solutions, leading to: 
$$
a=\sqrt{L},\qquad b=\sqrt{L},\qquad h={S\over4\sqrt{L}},\qquad
{P\over4}=2\sqrt{L} + {S\over 4\sqrt{L}},
$$
and
$$
a={1\over2\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{S}\pm\sqrt{S-8L} \right),\quad
b={1\over2\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{S}\mp\sqrt{S-8L} \right),\quad
h=\sqrt{S\over2},\qquad
{P\over4}=\sqrt{2S}.
$$
The minimum of $P/4$ is given by the first result if $S\le 8L$,
while for $S\ge 8L$ the minimum is given by the second result.

Your idea of setting $a+b=S/(2h)$, so that $P/4=h+S/(2h)$ is a function of $h$ only, does not work, because the constraint $ab=L$ entails $a+b\ge2\sqrt{L}$ and thus $h={S\over2(a+b)}\le S/(4\sqrt{L})$. Your solution $h=\sqrt{S/2}$ is then valid only if $\sqrt{S/2}\le S/(4\sqrt{L})$, that is if $S\ge8L$.

Comment: I've written my solution in full and also simplified noticeably some expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lagrange multipliers approach you find either the equations

\begin{eqnarray*} 
1 + \lambda a + 2h\mu = 0 \\
1 + \lambda b + 2h\mu = 0 \\
h + S\mu = 0 \\
ab = L \\
2h(a+b) = S
\end{eqnarray*}
which may be solved to give
$$ a = \sqrt{L},~ b = \sqrt{L}, ~h = {S \over 4\sqrt{L}}, $$
or (if $\lambda = 0$) the equations
$$ 1 + 2h\mu = 0, ~~ h+S\mu = 0, ~~ ab = L, ~~ 2h(a+b) = S, $$
which recovers the solution(s) you gave above. These solutions offer the *possible* critical points of the perimeter function.  It also has the benefit of optimizing all three variables simultaneously.

In solving we find that if $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\lambda = (S-8L)/L^{3/2}$.  This demonstrates that the parameters $S$ and $L$ have singular behavior when $S = 8L$, which was also indicated by the method you used above.

To find the minimum note that the perimeter comes out to 
$$ P/4 = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 2 \sqrt{L} + {S \over 4\sqrt{L}} & (\lambda \neq 0) \\
\sqrt{2S} & (\lambda = 0, S \geq 8L) \end{array} \right. $$
for the two possible solutions.  The top solution is correct only if 
$$ 2\sqrt{L} + {S \over 4\sqrt{L}} \leq \sqrt{2S} ~ \Rightarrow ~ (\sqrt{S} - \sqrt{8L})^2 \leq 0~ \Rightarrow ~S = 8L, $$
and in this case the two solutions coincide. It is possible the first solution gives the *maximum* possible perimeter, but more likely these are saddle points or local maxima when $S > 8L$.

When $S < 8L$ we see the top solution is the only real valued critical point, is physical, and on physical grounds can assume it is indeed the minimum possible perimeter value.

Let's simplify things by assuming $L=1$ and writing $P/4$ as a function of $a$:
$$ P/4 = a + {1 \over a} + {S\over 2(a + 1/a)}. $$
What is happening is that for small values of $S$ the third term (representing $h$) will make a small contribution to the perimeter regardless of the choice of $a$.  The first two terms are minimized at $a = \sqrt{L} = 1$, and allowing $a$ to take values away from that minimum cannot be compensated by a large drop in the ${S \over 2 (a + 1/a)}$ term.  However, for large $S$ values, making the $a + 1/a$ term *larger* may more than counteract the growth of the first two terms with a drop in the third.  For large $S$ then we expect two minima (since $a \neq b$ and the equations are symmetric in the two variables) but we expect only one minimum for very small choices of $S$.  The two regimes are separated by $S = 8 = 8L$.

Comment: You say that your solution optimizes all variables simultaneously, but consider $S = 12L$. Your solution yields $P/4 = \sqrt{25L}$ while mine yields $P/4 = \sqrt{24L} < \sqrt{25L}$.

Comment: @Minethlos I've just edited my solution to show that it encompasses both cases.

Comment: I omitted the possibility that one of the multipliers be zero, the other nonzero.  Including this case recovers your solution.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give the full solution and hopefully some helpful discussion of why one could expect a transition from your two solutions to a single minimum perimeter value.